# Product of unitary and anti-unitary operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, linear-algebra, unitarity

I'm pretty sure the product should be anti-unitary but I can't seem to be able to prove it. Say A is anti unitary and L is unitary. We can write:

$$\left\langle AL\phi|AL\psi\right\rangle =\left\langle A\phi L^{\dagger}|A\psi L^{\dagger}\right\rangle =\left\langle A\phi L|A\psi L\right\rangle $$

But how is it possible to proceed? I should get to $\left\langle \psi|\phi\right\rangle $ eventually, considering my guess is right.

Comment: Is *L* the same as *U*? Eventually? Do you know the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiunitary_operator)? Have you tried the example provided? Did you search this site for "anti-unitary"?

Comment: I wrote U when I meant L, I edited. I do know the definition and I couldn't find anything on the web using dirac notation.

Comment: So what notation is the WP article I linked to in? Take *L=I* for starters.

Comment: Your notation is highly unconventional. For example, what does $|A\psi L\rangle$ mean?!

Comment: It's the vector resulted from acting on it the operator A from the left and L from the right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is antiunitary and $L$ is unitary, then $AL$ is indeed antiunitary.  Note simply that
$$\langle AL\psi, AL\phi\rangle = \langle L\phi,L\psi\rangle = \langle\phi,\psi\rangle$$
and that $AL$ is invertible with $(AL)^{-1}=L^{-1}A^{-1}$.

---

> It's the vector resulted from acting on it the operator A from the left and L from the right

This doesn't make sense, I'm afraid.  It sounds like you've been confused by Dirac notation.

Given a vector $\psi$ in the Hilbert space, we define the bra $\langle \psi, \cdot\rangle \equiv \langle \psi|$ and ket $\langle \cdot,\psi\rangle \equiv |\psi\rangle$ to be the objects obtained by plugging $\psi$ into the first and second slot of the inner product, respectively, and leaving the other slot empty.  We then define $\langle \psi|\phi \rangle \equiv \langle \psi,\phi\rangle$.

Given some **linear** operator $L$, we define $\langle\psi|L|\phi\rangle \equiv \left< \psi, L(\phi)\right> = \langle L^\dagger (\psi),\phi\rangle$. Therefore, we say that $L$ can act on kets from the *left* as $L|\phi\rangle = |L(\phi)\rangle$ or on *bras* from the *right* as $\langle \psi|L = \left< L^\dagger (\psi)\right|$.  It does **not** make sense to write $|L_1\psi L_2\rangle$; once you've brought the operator "inside the bracket," it's just a function $L:\psi\mapsto L(\psi)$ and there's no meaningful notion of left or right action.

If an operator $A$ is **anti**linear, then you run into more serious problems when you try to define its action on a bra from the right.  For example, if $\lambda\in \mathbb C$ we would naively have,
$$\lambda\langle\psi|A|\phi\rangle =\langle\overline\lambda\psi|A|\phi\rangle = \langle A^\dagger(\overline\lambda \psi),\phi\rangle = \langle\lambda A^\dagger(\psi),\phi\rangle=\overline\lambda \langle A^\dagger(\psi),\phi\rangle = \overline\lambda \langle\psi|A|\phi\rangle$$
where we've used the fact that $A^\dagger$ is also antilinear.  Obviously this is unacceptable, and so most sources (e.g. Sakurai) simply refuse to try to define the action of antilinear operators from the right. In fact, the problem is that the correct definition of the adjoint of an antilinear operator has that

$$\langle \psi, A(\phi)\rangle = \overline{\langle A^\dagger (\psi),\phi\rangle}$$

but as you may be able to see, this doesn't play nicely with bra-ket notation.

Comment: A small comment: OP defined $A$ to be an antiunitary and $L$ as a unitary operator (and not the other way around).

Comment: @Jakob Thanks for the catch - I've updated my answer to conform to the notation in the question.

Comment: @J.Murray  thank you for the great answer. I have 2 followup questions. why did $\lambda$ became conjugated, when it went into the bra. In addition, is this reasoning OK $\langle AL\psi, AL\phi\rangle = \left(\langle \psi,AL AL\phi\rangle\right)^{*} = \left(\langle\psi,\phi\rangle\right)^{*}=\langle\phi,\psi\rangle $ using the definition of an anti-linear operator $\langle O\psi,\phi\rangle=\left(\langle \psi,O \phi\rangle\right)^{*}$. i.e. $ALAL=1$ then?

Comment: @AlexanderCska 1) That follows from the conjugate-linearity of the inner product, which says that $\langle \lambda \psi,\phi\rangle = \overline{\lambda}\langle \psi,\phi\rangle$. 2) In your last expression, that should be $\langle O\psi,\phi\rangle = \overline{\langle \psi, O^\color{red}{\dagger}\phi\rangle}$. You left out the $\dagger$, so the rest of the expression is incorrect.

Comment: @J.Murray Thanks! Most probably I got it wrong. I was thinking about an anti-linear operator acting on the dual space $\langle \psi|$ i.e. $\langle O\psi|\phi\rangle=\left(\langle \psi|O \phi\rangle\right)^{*}$ which is the version of $\langle O\psi|\phi\rangle=\langle \psi|O \phi\rangle$ for hermitian operators.
I think that you had in mind the adjoint for anti-linear operators $\langle \phi | B^{ \dagger} \psi\rangle=\left[\langle \psi B| \phi \rangle\right]^{*}$, which is the anti-linear version of $\langle \phi |A ^{\dagger} |\psi\rangle=\left( \langle \psi|A|\phi \rangle \right)^{*}$